# Android Studio: Facebook get access Tokken

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I would like to get an Access Token for accessing the Graph for my Application, without using the Facebook.Login button. (The button is actually placed in the Action Bar).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onSuccess from LoginResult you can get AccessToken).

```
if (callbackManager == null) {
          callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }


          LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
              });


    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

Comment: This is not returning anything

Comment: *do - It fails at doing anything